Prove that if there is $a\in \mathbb R$, $2x + y = a - 2$ and $4xy = a² + 3a + 1$, then $x\in[-3,0]$ and $y\in[-6,0]$
You have to arrive at $(2x + 3)² \le 9$ and $(y + 3)² \le 9$ after eliminating $a$ but I'm struggling to find out how
Thanks in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is false. Take $a=-1$ and $y=a-2-2x=-3-2x$ with
$$
x=\frac{\sqrt{11}-3}{4}.
$$
Then the equations are solved, but $x>0$, a contradiction.

Thank you. Looks like there was a mistake made when the problem was written.

@zyrgyr Perhaps a typo. Do you have an image of the exercise? Then we could compare.

This is the exact problem, it's from a math's book, I checked it many times. It's definitely a typo on the original creator's part.
